# Unpermitted parameter on relationship fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Ruby on Rails' forms helpers and reading the https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html document I'm trying an exercise in my computer but it simply won't work as described in the document, all I get is

```
    Started POST "/players" for ::1 at 2023-09-15 22:48:45 -0600
    Processing by PlayersController#create as TURBO_STREAM
      Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "player"=>{"name"=>"Luis", "number"=>"45",        "jersey"=>{"size"=>"M"}}, "commit"=>"Create Player"}
    Unpermitted parameter: :jersey. Context: { controller: PlayersController, action: create,   request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00007f117a4a0640>, params: {"authenticity_token"=>"   [FILTERED]", "player"=>{"name"=>"Luis", "number"=>"45", "jersey"=>{"size"=>"M"}},    "commit"=>"Create Player", "controller"=>"players", "action"=>"create"} }
```

And the Jersey relationship is not persisted.
I'm using Rails 7.0.8 and ruby 3.2.1 on an Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a Acer Nitro AN515-55

This is the code involved:
Models are: Player Has_many Jersey

```
    class Player < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :jerseys, dependent: :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :jerseys
    end
    class Jersey < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :player
    end
```

players_controller (only index, new, create and player_params)

```
# GET /players or /players.json
      def index
        @players = Player.all
        @player = Player.new
      end
    # GET /players/new
      def new
        @player = Player.new
      end
    # POST /players or /players.json
      def create
        @player = Player.new(player_params)
        respond_to do |format|
          if @player.save
            format.html { redirect_to players_url, notice: "Player was successfully created." }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @player }
          else
            format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            format.json { render json: @player.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
     # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
        def player_params
          params.require(:player).permit(:name, :number, jerseys_attributes: [:id, :size])
        end
```

I have the form in the index.htl.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: @player) do |form| %>
      <div>
        <%= form.label :name, style: "display: block" %>
        <%= form.text_field :name %>
      </div>

      <div>
        <%= form.label :number, style: "display: block" %>
        <%= form.number_field :number %>
      </div>

      <div>
        <%= form.fields_for :jersey do |jersey_form| %>
          <%= jersey_form.label :size, style: "display: block" %>
          <%= jersey_form.text_field :size %>
        <% end %>
      </div>

      <div>
        <%= form.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div id="players">
      <% @players.each do |player| %>
        <%= render player %>
        <p>
          <%= link_to "Show this player", player %>
        </p>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <%= link_to "New player", new_player_path %>
```

I have also tried with:

```
    <%= form.fields_for :jersey, @player.jerseys do |jersey_form| %>
```

But it is the same result... At this point I don't know what is wrong, this is a simple example but I cannot make it work, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :jerseys` which means:

```rb
#                      v
form.fields_for :jerseys do |jersey_form|
```

This way form builder can [detect](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.8/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L2671) `jerseys` association and generate correct `jerseys_attributes` input names.

---

**Update**

How about we start from scratch:

```bash
bin/rails g scaffold Player name number
bin/rails g model Jersey size player:references
bin/rails db:migrate
```

```rb
# app/models/jersey.rb
class Jersey < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :player
end

# app/models/player.rb
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jerseys, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :jerseys
end
```

```rb
# app/controllers/players_controller.rb

class PlayersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @player = Player.new
    @player.jerseys.new # build a nested object
  end

  def create
    @player = Player.new(player_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @player.save
        format.html { redirect_to player_url(@player), notice: "Created." }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def player_params
    params.require(:player).permit(:name, :number, jerseys_attributes: [:id, :size])
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/views/players/_form.html.erb

<%= form_with model: player do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :name %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>

  <%= form.label :number %>
  <%= form.text_field :number %>

  <%= form.fields_for :jerseys do |jersey_form| %>
    <%= jersey_form.label :size %>
    <%= jersey_form.text_field :size %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.submit %> 
<% end %>
```

Fill and submit:

```rb
Started POST "/players" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-09-16 22:42:06 -0400
Processing by PlayersController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "player"=>{"name"=>"asdf", "number"=>"1", "jerseys_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"size"=>"xl"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Player"}
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/players_controller.rb:10:in `block in create'
  Player Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "players" ("name", "number", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "asdf"], ["number", "1"], ["created_at", "2023-09-17 02:42:06.071928"], ["updated_at", "2023-09-17 02:42:06.071928"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/players_controller.rb:10:in `block in create'
  Jersey Create (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "jerseys" ("size", "player_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["size", "xl"], ["player_id", 1], ["created_at", "2023-09-17 02:42:06.074850"], ["updated_at", "2023-09-17 02:42:06.074850"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/players_controller.rb:10:in `block in create'
  TRANSACTION (7.3ms)  commit transaction
# PERSISTED            ^^^^^^
  ↳ app/controllers/players_controller.rb:10:in `block in create'
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/players/1
```

Index action literally works the same:

```rb
def index
  @players = Player.all

  @player = Player.new
  @player.jerseys.new
end
```

```rb
# app/views/players/index.html.erb

<%= render "form", player: @player %>
```

Comment: I also tried that, but doing so the '.fields_for' part won't be rendered in the form, leaving me just with the Player fields... I tried with: :jerseys and :jerseys, @player.jerseys... No solution

Comment: @FernandoFlores that's correct. i should have mentioned, when you use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` your nested fileds are linked to the nested objects. so you have to build them in your `new` controller action and anywhere else you need it, like this: `@player = Player.new; @player.jerseys.new` - now you have one jersey that will be rendered by the `fields_for` helper. if you do `@player.jerseys.new` again, you will have two objects and two sets of fields.

Comment: ... And, still unpermitted params and no jerseys persisted: `("player"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Tom Brady", "number"=>"12"} permitted: false>, "jerseys"=>{"size"=>"s"}, "commit"=>"Create Player", "controller"=>"players", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
(ruby) player_params
#<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Tom Brady", "number"=>"12"} permitted: true>

  Player Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "players" ("name", "number", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Tom Brady"], ["number", 12]

Comment: `def player_params
      params.require(:player).permit(:name, :number, jerseys_attributes: [:id, :size])
    end`

Comment: `def index
    @players = Player.all
    @player = Player.new
    @player.jerseys.new
  end` Still no jersey persisted

Comment: Yes, that did work... So what was wrong with using the nested form in the index action? Still not understanding

Comment: @FernandoFlores i've double checked just in case) but it works exactly the same on the index action. just keep an eye on the Parameters that are being submitted, you should have `"jerseys_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"size"=>"sm"}` there, which is coming from the input `name` attribute `name="player[jerseys_attributes][0][size]"` if you're not seeing that, you're doing something wrong, which i cannot really tell from what you have posted so far. I've added Index action as well ^